# Screenshot includes selection window with screenshot

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, screenshot

Here is a normal screenshot:

[image]

Here is a broken screenshot including the "selection" window.

[image]

I have the "printscreen" keyboard bound directly to "Copy a screenshot of an area to clipboard"

Comment: `man gnome-screenshot` has `-B, --remove-border` to `Remove the window border from the screenshot`. I can't verify if this is what you need because I'm not using the GNOME environment at the moment.

Comment: Its not a border problem as I believe, its the overlay that is shown to the user to display which region they are screenshooting. This overlay is included in the actual screenshot.